# When a JS var has the value 0 (zero), controller API replaces it with empty field (2sxc - DNN)

Tags: javascript, c#, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I use 2sxc (DNN) to pass some form data into an entity trough this js:

```
$2sxc(@Dnn.Module.ModuleID).webApi.post("Controller/Create", {}, { 
        qtitle: "@Content.title",
        date: $todaydate,
        user: "@Dnn.User.Username",
        q1sel: $q1res,
        q1val: $q1val
        }
```

And this controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [DnnModuleAuthorize(AccessLevel = SecurityAccessLevel.Admin)]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public bool Create(dynamic postController)
    {
        var quizvals = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        quizvals.Add("qtitle", postController.qtitle.ToString());
        quizvals.Add("date", postController.date.ToString());
        quizvals.Add("user", postController.user.ToString());
        quizvals.Add("q1sel", postController.q1sel.ToString());

        App.Data.Create("Quiz10q5o_entries", quizvals, "Anonymous");

        return true;
    }
```

I tried quite a few data types and they all work fine, with or without ToString, but when any of the $vars has a 0 (zero, JS numeric), the field is passed has empty into the entity row.

Can anyone help me understand why this happens? Is some type of conversion needed here?

Best regards,
João Gomes

Comment: Why are you using dynamic?

Comment: What would you suggest?

Comment: Could you inspect the network tab in the browser?  What data is posted to the server?

Comment: @RUKAclMortality     q3val: $q3val.toFixed(2) --> q3val: "0.00"    q4val: $q4val --> q4val: 0    Any other value, with or without quotes, will store just fine. Zero values, with or without quotes, with or without tofixed, will store as empty.

Comment: Full request: {"qtitle":"quizbav","date":"2017-9-23","user":"eXistenZe","reference":"","q1sel":"1","q1val":"0.00","q2sel":"4","q2val":"0.00","q3sel":"5","q3val":"10.00","q4sel":"4","q4val":0,"q5sel":"5","q5val":0,"q6sel":"4","q6val":0,"q7sel":"5","q7val":0,"q8sel":"4","q8val":10,"q9sel":"5","q9val":0,"q10sel":"4","q10val":0,"total":"20.00"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reviewed your work and it doesn't look like anything is wrong. It also seems to write 0 into the number field, as it should:

[image]

to me it looks like just the list-view in admin hides these values:

[image]

Could it be that this is all?

Comment: I feel ashamed to admit that yes, the only problem is in the list-view. Never thought about actually opening the record to check since there actually is no need to edit a submission.

Thanks again.

One last note: what is the right format to submit a date?

Comment: Nevermind. It's yyyy-dd-mm (weird as in the custom controller I had it accepted yyyy-mm-dd)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are writing to a number-field, and using a string. Try casting it to a Int32 or similar and I believe you should be good to go.

Comment: Since I have no C# knowledge I copied your controller demos which have: Dictionary<string, object>(); So I cannot cast to int32 inside (it will complain input string was not in the correct format). How can I accomplish this?

Comment: first, please test the assumption that it's a string / int issue. Basically create a number in your c# which is simply written into it, like:
`quizvals.Add("numberfield", 0);` to verify this.

Comment: ...then you could try `quizvals.Add("q7val", postController.q7val);` next (without converting it to string)...

Comment: and last-but-not least: if all you want to do is just write data, then using a custom Webapi isn't the recommended way (a bit too hard). Instead, you might just want to use the existing REST api.  https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/wiki/WebApi

Comment: Both options have the same stored result (empty). The network request logged is the same (0). I'll try your demo app for the REST api. Thanks.

Comment: Tried REST api but the problem remains...  And now the date also stores empty... https://pastebin.mozilla.org/9068571

Comment: Could you post your app? it just makes it faster to duplicate, could be a 2sxc bug.

Comment: Can you send me a private contact (e-mail)?

Comment: please use info 2sxc org